# What command should I use to rm all .png files in a folder and subfolder?

Tags: command-line, rm, photo, png

I started with this based off of another question I had:

```
find -type f -iname '*.png' -exec rm
```

that clearly didn't work, but am I atleast warm?

Comment: You could replace the `-exec rm` part with `-delete`.

Answer (score 6):

You were very close:

```
find -type f -iname '*.png' -exec rm {} \;
```

As edwinksl pointed out, using `-delete` flag also works:

```
find -type f -iname '*.png' -delete
```

In `bash` shell alone we can do

```
shopt -s globstar
rm ./**/*.png
```

This, however, might suffer from `Arguments list too long` error, if number of files expanded is large, or environment passed to the command is also large. As always, remember to append `echo rm ./**/*.png` to see what will actually run.